# How to extract a dataframe which is within a list in r, using a condition?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, conditional-statements, subset

I have a list which has dataframes of various dimensions. I want to extract those dataframes who rows greater than 30
I tried :

```
DR<-sapply(list, function(x) subset(list,nrow(list$'x')=30))
```

But it is showing error.
Please help!

Comment: I tried one more way:                                                                                                    
for(i in 1:length(list))
D<-subset(list ,dim(list$'i')[1]>30) But I'm getting an output as named list()

Comment: Please don't post multiple posts with same question, instead improve your current post. Can you update your post with `dput(aw)` ?

Comment: Sorry for multiple duplicate posts. I will update dput(aw) shortly.

Comment: I found a easier way to do it                                                                                                     for (x in list)
{
if (dim(x)[1]>30)                                                                                                print(x)                                                                                                                  
      }                                                                                
Now how to append the dataframes into a new list? I tried creating a blank list at beginning of loop, tried append function.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your list is called `list_df`, we can use `Filter`

```
Filter(function(x) nrow(x) == 30, list_df)
```

Or `sapply`

```
list_df[sapply(list_df, nrow) == 30]
```

---

We can also use `purrr::keep`

```
purrr::keep(list_df, ~nrow(.) == 30)
```

Comment: It is showing error that the object is not a matrix

Comment: @ChinmayJoshi In that case, you need to share your data. Can you edit your question with output of `dput(lapply(list, head, n = 5))` ?

Comment: > dput(lapply(list, head, n = 5))
OUTPUT- list(NULL)

Comment: @ChinmayJoshi You said `I have a list which has dataframes of various dimensions.`. What is the name of the list in your R session ? Use that in the answer above instead of `list_df` and for `dput` as well.